# How to parse latitude, longitude from geography(POINT, 4326) using Psycopg in Python

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I am using PostGIS to save geography data in type geography(POINT, 4326).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  geog geography(POINT, 4326) NULL
)
```

And I am using Psycopg in Python to access data in PostGIS.

What is the best way to get the latitude, longitude?

One possible way is use ST_AsText:

```
select geog, ST_AsText(geog) from address
```

It will return geog as a string like POINT(104.5306 32.4089) and I can parse the string to get latitude and longitude.

Is there a better way do achieve what I want?

Comment: There are many ways of solving this task with Python. But why not to use `ST_X` and `ST_Y` functions in PostGIS?

Comment: "Best" questions are inherently subjective, so this may be closed as *opinion-based*. Given the simplicity of points, using `ST_X()` and `ST_Y()` for lon and lat (respectively) seems an obvious solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In postresql/postgis you can store up to 4D geometries XYZM.  To access the coordinates:

- `st_x` = x/longitude
- `st_y` = y/latitude
- `st_z` = z/altitude
- `st_m` = m/measure.

Please note that these functions only work with **geometry**, so you will need to cast your geography to geometry: `geog::geometry` or `cast(geog as geometry)`